# Nginx Server Block Configuration Issue - Conflicting Domains

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I have a clean installation of Nginx, specifically version 1.24.0, on my Amazon Linux 2023 server, and I'm facing an issue with the server block configuration. I have three server blocks set up for different domains: "adam.example.com," "testapi.example.com," and "testdesktop.example.com."

The problem is that when I access "adam.example.com," it displays the content of "testapi.example.com." If I remove the "testapi.example.com" block from the configuration, "adam.example.com" then displays the content of "testdesktop.example.com."

It's worth noting that my domain DNS is managed by Cloudflare, which may be relevant to the issue.

I've checked for any additional configuration files, and my Nginx configuration is stored in "example.com.conf" in the "conf.d" folder. Docker is also installed on the server.

I'd appreciate any help in resolving this issue and ensuring that each domain displays its intended content correctly on Nginx version 1.24.0 (Amazon Linux 2023) with Cloudflare-managed DNS. What might be causing this conflict, and how can I resolve it in my Nginx configuration?

here is my config file:

```
    server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name adam.example.com;

    location /
    {
        return 200 "Hello, welcome!!!!!";
    }

}

server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name testapi.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name testapi.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testapi.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/testapi.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root "/var/www/html/testapi.example.com";

    location /
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name testdesktop.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name testdesktop.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testdesktop.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/testdesktop.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Change this to your Docker container's host and port
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header CLIENT-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's me or your `adam.example.com` doesn't have an SSL-enabled server block? Why? Can you repeat the test from the *clean* browser profile which had not cached any of these redirect-to-SSL replies?

Comment: Yes, it does not have SSL because I should add a non-SSL block first. So, I ran Certbot to generate a certificate and add the SSL section automatically. However, I can't even load the non-SSL domain, and I get a timeout error.

Comment: As @TeroKilkanen suggested in their answer it might be wrong idea to test non-HTTPS with a browser, because modern browsers attempt HTTPS automatically. Try testing using `curl`, or manually, `telnet <ip> 80` and there `GET / HTTP/1.1<enter>Host: adam.example.com<enter><enter>`. See if it works this way, report, then we'll continue. Also, both suggestions down there are always good to go: split config to several files, each containing a trivial "redirect to https" server block and actual https server block; implement dedicated default_server catch-all server block with self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in nginx is to have an explicit default virtual host, for example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server; // if server has IPv6 address
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server; // if server has IPv6 address

    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/some/certificate_key;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/some/certificate;

    location / {
        return 444; // immediately disconnects sessions to default host
    }
}
```

What happens in your case is that your request is likely for `https://adam.example.com`. Since there is no matching virtual host for that (`adam.example.com` is only HTTP), nginx selects the available HTTPS virtual host to serve the request, in this case `testapi.example.com`.

When a default virtual host like above is defined, you will get a disconnection when making request to a virtual host that is not defined instead of getting another virtual host.

To make sure everything works as is, you need to take the following steps:

1. Determine what access you would like to use for each domain. HTTP, HTTPS or both?
2. After determining the required access, then make sure the virtual host configuration matches the requirements.

Also, make sure to test the connection with the connection method you want to use. Note that browsers can enforce `https` use everywhere, therefore testing the `http` virtual host should be done with `curl`.

Comment: there is already defualt server inside nginx.conf, should i add another manually?

Comment: Does one exist for both `http` and `https`?

Comment: here is the nginx.conf https://justpaste.it/bphbo

Comment: Your configuration does not have `default_server` for https on port 443.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to do those 3 domains in 3 seperate files in the sites-available, creating three virtual hosts. And then of course link them to sites-enabled

You can test with `nginx -t`

Here is an example of one of such a vhost which you need to save in /etc/nginx/sites-available/, as domain1 for example.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/robotsandcake/6841680/raw/9e67fe6fc64f6137a6e7cea454a06b9e3c2af0f3/example-virtualhost